# How to make visual studio code detect glad.h in visual studio code, ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, visual-studio-code, glad

I already tried altering the c_cpp_properties file to include the path where glad.h is installed, like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${default}",
                "/home/jose_miguel/Desktop/simulador/librerias"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": 
                "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I have even copy-pasted the glad.h file to usr/bin, where most executables are (including g++) and vs code will still not detect the file. The error being `"glad.h: no such file or directory"`.  Even intellisense brings up the file when you're writing it. Could someone please point me in the right direction.

I will post my code for reference's sake, it's a simple triangle in opengl:

```
#include <glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";
const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    // build and compile our shader program
    // ------------------------------------
    // vertex shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // fragment shader
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // link shaders
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left  
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // right 
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // top   
    }; 

    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 

    // You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
    // VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
    glBindVertexArray(0); 


    // uncomment this call to draw in wireframe polygons.
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // draw our first triangle
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO); // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        // glBindVertexArray(0); // no need to unbind it every time 
 
        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem but I don't think my solution was the best. Therefore, I won't post it as an answer. I got a list of all of my include directories and pasted it there. For some reason, `${default}` stopped working when I added other directories. /usr/bin doesn't contain header files and it's not an include path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got this to work for me, all answers I've found are way more complicated than they need to be.

tl;dr: add glad.c to your g++ compilation command in tasks.json (example below)

As per this documentation https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window

> Go to the GLAD web service, make sure the language is set to C++, and
> in the API section select an OpenGL version of at least 3.3 (which is
> what we'll be using; higher versions are fine as well). Also make sure
> the profile is set to Core and that the Generate a loader option is
> ticked. Ignore the extensions (for now) and click Generate to produce
> the resulting library files.
>
> GLAD by now should have provided you a zip file containing two include
> folders, and a single glad.c file. Copy both include folders (glad and
> KHR) into your include(s) directoy (or add an extra item pointing to
> these folders), and add the glad.c file to your project.

Once downloaded, add the include folders `usr/local/include`

```
cd glad/include
cp -r glad/ KHR/ /usr/include/
```

and the `glad.c` file to the root of the project in vscode.

Then in your `tasks.json` file, it should look something like this

```json
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      ...

      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "glad.c",
        "-lglfw",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],

      ... 

    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

So you have to include the glad.c file in your compilation command.

And of course import the glad header before the glfw one.

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```